# Do You Need a Permit to Cook Free Food on the Sidewalk?

Tags: california, food, restaurants

I'd like to open a food stand in Los Angeles to cook food for homeless people. Do I need a permit of some sort to cook food and give it away free of charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [LA County Public Health Department](http://publichealth.lacounty.gov/eh/misc/ehdef.htm):

> "Food facility" means an operation that stores, prepares, packages,
>   serves, vends, or otherwise provides food for human consumption at the
>   retail level, including, but not limited to, the following:
>
> - An operation where food is consumed on or off the premises, **regardless of whether there is a charge for the food**.
> - Any place used in conjunction with the operations described in this subdivision, including, but not limited to, storage facilities
>     for food-related utensils, equipment, and materials.

So your food stand is a "food facility" for the purposes of the law.  As such, as far as I can tell, you would be subject to the same permit and inspection requirements as any other similar food facility, like a commercial food stand.

Comment: ooh perhaps I could slip into this clause if I register as a nonprofit and attach myself to an 'event' (which also seems vaguely defined)? '"Food facility" does not include any of the following: A for-profit entity that gives or sells food at an event that occurs not more than three days in a 90-day period for the benefit of a nonprofit association, if the for-profit entity receives no monetary benefit, other than that resulting from recognition from participating in an event.'

Comment: @cdipaolo: Information on requirements for community events can be found [here](http://publichealth.lacounty.gov/eh/DSE/CommunityEvent.htm).  It seems that there are some exemptions, but they're narrow.